# error by passing tests it shouldn't on nrgx selector testing

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx-store

I want to test the state given by a selector with MockStore and override but I am doing something wrong because no matter what I expect I always pass the test.

I followed the example in https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile.component';
import {MemoizedSelector} from '@ngrx/store';

import * as profileSelectors from '../../../app/store/selectors/profile.selectors';
import {AppState} from '../../../app/store';
import {MockStore, provideMockStore} from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import {By} from 'protractor';
import {ProfileState} from '../../../app/store/reducers/profile.reducer';


describe('UserProfileComponent', () => {
  let component: UserProfileComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserProfileComponent>;
  let store: MockStore<AppState>;
  let mockShowsSelector;
  // I wrote the same as in the example
  const queryDivText = () =>
    fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('div'))[0].nativeElement.textContent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [provideMockStore()],
      declarations: [UserProfileComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserProfileComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    mockShowsSelector = store.overrideSelector(profileSelectors.getUserInfo, {
      id: 2,
      user: 'user',
      role: 'role',
      email:email 'description 2'
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
  // I wrote the same as in the example
  it('should greet John when the username is John', () => {
    expect(queryDivText()).toBe('Greetings, John!');
  });
});
```

In the code above you can see my problem.. Even if it tests something random (that is not even in my component view) it passes the test. I think it has to do with the debugelement.

Comment: can you share UserProfileComponent code that you're writing unit test for?

Comment: I think you'll have to do `store.refreshState()` immediately after `mockShowsSelector = store.overrideSelector(...)`